Derivation of "Euclidean Lorentz transforms" without the one-way speed-of-light constancy postulate but with the relativity principle
Here is the derivation of Euclidean "Lorentz transformations" by Gemini 1.5 Pro from the basic postulates but without the one-way speed light constancy postulate. Do you find any faults in it?
Demonstrating the Euclidean Transformations from Basic Postulates
Instead of starting with the postulate of the constancy of the speed of light, let's take as our starting assumptions:

Principle of Relativity: The laws of physics are the same in all inertial reference frames.
Homogeneity and Isotropy of Space: Space is homogeneous (the same physical laws apply at every point) and isotropic (the same physical laws apply in all directions).
Linear Transformation: The transformation between the coordinates (t, x) and (t', x') of two inertial reference frames is linear.

Derivation:

Linearity: Due to the linearity assumption, the transformations can be written in the form:
t' = at + bx

x' = ct + dx

where a, b, c and d are constants to be determined.

Origin of the Frames: Consider that the origin of S' moves at a velocity β in the positive x direction relative to S.  This implies that when x' = 0, we have x = βt. Substituting this into the second equation, we get:
0 = ct + dβt

For this equation to be true for all t, we must have c = -βd.

Symmetry: The principle of relativity implies that the inverse transformations must have the same form as the direct transformations, with v replaced by -v. This means that:
t = at' - bx'

x = -ct' + dx'


Combining the Equations: By combining the direct and inverse equations, we can eliminate x and t and obtain equations for a and d:

Substituting  x from the second inverse equation into the first direct equation:
t' = at + b((-ct' + dx') - βt)/d

Simplifying and rearranging, we get:
t'(d + bc) = t(ad - bβ) 


Substituting  t from the first inverse equation into the second direct equation:
x' = c(at' - bx')/a + d(at' - bx')

Simplifying and rearranging, we get:
x'(a - bc) = t'(ca + daβ)




Solving for a and d:

Now we have two equations:

t'(d + bc) = t(ad - bβ)
x'(a - bc) = t'(ca + daβ)


Since these equations must hold for all values of t and t', the coefficients must be equal:

d + bc = 0
ad - bβ = 1
a - bc = 1
ca + daβ = 0


We already know that c = -βd. Substituting this into the above equations, we can solve for a and d:

From d + bc = 0, we get d - β²d = 0  => d(1 - β²) = 0. Since  β < 1, we have  d ≠ 0, therefore  1 - β² = 0, which is not possible.  This means this equation is not useful.

From ad - bβ = 1 and c = -βd, we get ad + β²d = 1  => d(a + β²) = 1.

From a - bc = 1 and c = -βd, we get a + β²d = 1.

Combining the last two equations, we get  d(a + β²) = a + β²d.  Since  d ≠ 0,  we have  a = d.

Finally, substituting  a = d  into  d(a + β²) = 1, we get  a² (1 + β²) = 1  =>  a² = d² = 1/(1 + β²) = γ²





Final Transformations: Substituting the values of a, b, c, and d, we obtain the Euclidean transformations:
t' = t/γ - βx

x' = x/γ + βt



Conclusion:
We have derived the Euclidean transformations using assumptions different from those of special relativity, namely the principle of relativity, homogeneity and isotropy of space, and the linearity of transformations. This derivation highlights the link between these transformations and a "classical"  conception of spacetime, where velocities add linearly. It suggests that these transformations could be the foundation of an alternative theory to special relativity, which remains to be explored in more detail.

A full derivation along those lines is found in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/24/3/312 and references therein, specially the one by Lévy-Leblond.

Comment to the post (v2): Is this about Euclidean signature? If not consider to replace the word Euclidean with the word linear or the word affine.

Why replace the word Euclidean ? This is a euclidean rotation instead of a hyperbolic one.

I have already look at it myself and didn't find any fault. This derivation mean spacetime may have an euclidean metric :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulations_of_special_relativity#Euclidean_relativity

@Verktaj : Gemini criticized the paper you linked to:
https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0302045
The solution given in this paper is not general and does not contain the Euclidean transformations because it contains a hidden restrictive assumption.

Closing questions that do not fall within the specified criteria is part of the stackexchange policy. Stackexchange makes guidelines for 'what is a good question' available. You are not entitled to an answer. The thing is: demanding an answer is a sure way of alienating any possible audience you might have.

That spacetime doesn't have a Euclidean metric is actually fairly easy to observe: time and space are distinctly different, 4 vectors like energy+momentum do not rotate like Euclidean 4 vectors. You can make Minkowski's metric "look" Euclidean by introducing imaginary time, and indeed that was Minkowski's original formulation, but the end behavior is very different from simple Euclidean $R^4$.
It's already well known in the literature that if one assumes the principle of relativity and homogeneity and isotropy of space then it follows that there are only 3 possibilities for the transformation between frames: the Euclidean, Galilean, and Lorentzian transformations. The LLM is basically regurgitating these arguments, but without insight.
Determining which of the 3 possibilities actually works in our universe is then a matter of experiment. As mentioned above Euclidean spacetime is ruled out easily and has never been seriously considered as a model for our universe. Galilean spacetime was the favored model for a long time, but it too has now been ruled out by experiment.

This answer is an argument from authority. This is not an answer to the question.

Time and space are different because space is 3-vector and time is a scalar, like in the algebra of physical space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_physical_space and the quaternions. APS may have an euclidean metric.

@user419029 This answer is not an appeal to authority. It is simply choosing an option that is consistent with what is measured in real experiments. That's a different thing.

Euclidean equations are also consistent with what is measured.
By the way, even if I don't agree with the presentation, euclidian spacetime can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulations_of_special_relativity#Euclidean_relativity

@user419029 : Completely separate space and time (a la Galileo and Newton) is certainly a logical possibility given the conditions given, and would correspond to the original system of linear equations having $a=d=1, b=0, c=\beta$. Yet that isn't consistent with the LLM's final answer, so clearly the LLM went wrong. Step 5 of the argument (beginning with "the coefficients must be equal") doesn't make much sense. I also see an entirely unjustified assumption that $\beta < 1$. As usual, the LLM has produced some text that seems superficially plausible but is missing important details.

The "Euclidean relativity" you linked to uses proper time $\tau$ rather than coordinate time $t$, so it's not at all the same as what you and Gemini were discussion. A Euclidean spacetime in the ordinary meaning of the term would mean a spacetime in which time and space coordinates were on a completely equal footing, and definitely does not correspond to our world. The SF writer and mathematician Greg Egan wrote about a parallel universe in which the transformation is Euclidean in the Orthogonal series: https://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/ORTHOGONAL.html

They are not on a completely equal footing, space is vectors and time is scalar. It's APS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_physical_space The euclidian relativity on Wikipedia is wrong. But both share the same euclidean rotation.  But this derivation seems faulty. Thanks for your feedback.

The algebra of physical space uses paravectors rather than vectors, so it's not a Euclidean vector space.

It is not a Euclidean vector space, since there are 3 vectors and a scalar, but the metric can be given as Euclidean, like that of quaternions, which have a Euclidean metric and which are moreover a subset of APS.
